# Bit swapping and pointer

Tags: c++, byte, swap, endianness

I have a `struct`, which is composed of multiple 32 bits elements. I applied a `#pragma pack (4)`, the following struct is therefore linear and aligned.

```
struct
{
  int a; // 4 bytes
  int b; // 4 bytes
  int c; // 4 bytes
} mystruct; // total 16 bytes
```

How can I swap each of these elements (little -> big endian) ?

The method is `void swap(void* a, int b);`, with `a` pointer to the structure, and `b` integer giving the size of the structure.

For example :

```
void swap(void* a, int b)
{
  //FIXME !
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i+= 32)
  {
    a = (a & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (a & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
    a = (a & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (a & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;
    a += 32;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your element d is not four bytes it's one byte. By using `#pragma pack(4)` you have forced the compiler to add three padding bytes after element d, but it is still an error for your code to access those bytes. If you really want four bytes what's wrong with `char d[4];`?

Comment: @john post edited, this is not what I am looking for. Now let's say the struct is only composed of 3 int.

Comment: By the way, your current pragma is probably obsolete, since a struct full of `int`s is aligned at least to the alignment of `int`, which is most likely at least 4 bytes. On the other hand I cannot see why you assume the struct to be aligned to 16 bytes (except maybe if you think that `#pragma pack` considers elements instead of bytes, which it of course doesn't).

Comment: Do you mean byte-swapping rather than bit-swapping. endian changing is byte-swapping, not bit.

Comment: @ChristianRau the struct is not full of `int`, I cleaned the example to make it easier to understand. When by "aligned", I meant that elements of the struct follow each other in the memory

Comment: @Patouf Well, as it stands it **is** full of `int`s, or do you see any other data in there. Still your comment about *"total 16 bytes"* probably applies to some older version of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can swap two bytes without using a temporary:

```
void byteswap( unsigned char & a, unsigned char & b )
{
   a ^= b;
   b ^= a;
   a ^= b;
}
```

Now let's apply it to numbers of variable length

```
template< typename T >
void endianSwap( T & t )
{
    unsigned char * first = reinterpret_cast< unsigned char * >( &t );
    unsigned char * last = first + sizeof(T) - 1;
    while( first < last )
    {
       byteswap( *first, *last );
       ++first;
       --last;
    }
}
```

For your struct you can:

```
void endianSwap( mystruct & s )
{
     endianSwap( s.a );
     endianSwap( s.b );
     endianSwap( s.c );
}
```

Of course, as an alternative to endianSwap using byteswap, we could just use std::reverse.

```
template<typename T> endianSwap( T& t )
{
    unsigned char * begin = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&t);
    unsigned char * end = begin + sizeof( T );
    std::reverse( begin, end );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible fix for your routine

```
void swap(void* a, int b)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i += 4)
  {
    int* p = (char*)a + i;
    *p = (*p & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (*p & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
    *p = (*p & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (*p & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;
  }
}
```

Untested, but a bit closer to correct I hope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a *nix based machine. There is a useful functions can do that:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostint32);   // from host to network
                                      // means little to big if your machine is x86
```

Comment: if you want to swap to big endian. However if you want to swap from big to little that function won't work.

Comment: So what? There is also `ntohl`.

Comment: @Patouf Basically yes. There is another version for short.

Comment: yes but if you are on a big endian platform it won't work to swap to little endian. Of course, you could use this as implementation for little endian systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(void* A, int b)
{
   //FIXME !
   int *c = (int*)A; // have to cast to an existing type. 'void' doesnt exist
   for (int i = 0; i < b; i+=4)  // we are flipping 4 bytes at a time
   {
        unsigned int a=*c;  // read the content, not the address
         // have to have unsigned, otherwise (a&0xff00ff00)>>8 extends the sign bit
        a = (a & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (a & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
        a = (a & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (a & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;
        *c++= a;  // write back the content
   }
 }
```

Anyway: my favourite way to do byte swapping in c or c-like languages is through a copy:
The concept is easier to remember than the name of a builtin function.

`void swap(char *d, char *s, int N) { for (i=0;i<N;i++) d[i^3]=*s++;}`

Comment: This code assumes the size b is the size in ints. Might be right, but I think it's more likely to be the size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by little->big endian you mean reversing the order of the bytes in each 4-byte element. I also assume that by "`a` null pointer on the structure" you mean "`a` pointer on the structure".
There are a few errors in your code. Try this:

```
void swap(void* a, int b)
{
  for (int *pInt = (int *)a; pInt < ((char *)a + b); pInt++)
  {
    *pInt = (*pInt & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (*pInt  & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
    *pInt = (*pInt & 0x00FF00FF) << 8 | (*pInt & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8;
  }
}
```